# Can I put class base components inside function base components to use react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks, stripe-payments

I have an app that was written mainly with class base react components, however we are implementing a paywall feature with Stripe.

The issue is stripe uses hooks, which don't work with class base components. Is it possible to put a child class base component into a parental function base component in order to achieve this. How would I go about doing this without rewriting every component as a function base component.

Every attempt to include a function base component with class base children always yields this error:

Error: Invalid hook call.  Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Are there any work arounds, or should I re-write the all the components as functional components?

A quick example using react-router-dom for query parameters, then passing those into a class base child component.

```
 function useQuery() {
   return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
 }

const App = () => {
let query = useQuery();

return (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          {/* Public Pages */}
          <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} ref={query.get('ref')} /> 
       </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
)
}
 export default App;
```

Then assuming that the landing components is a simple class base component that will set the prop into the state.

Comment: If you could put some code example on the files you are working , so can help you better. Absolutely you can use Functional Components as Parent and Class component as child,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured out the issue with this problem. Since I found the same question unanswered on the internet, I decided to answer the question myself, Just for future reference for anyone looking for the same solution I was running into.

You can use Hooks on a parental Function Base Component and pass on the information into a child base component.

While rendering the application, I was given an error

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

However this error was due to outdated modules in npm. I just updated the react-router-dom from 4.1 to 5.2.0 `npm update react-router-dom` and it seem to solve the issue of using functional base component as a parent.

After updating the module I was able to use a hooks in a parental function base component and pass that on to a child class base component using props.

Answer (score 0):

Component's type doesn't matter in relation parent-child. But you can't use hooks inside of classBased component. Only in functional ones

Comment: Hi, while i appreciate the comment. I more concerned with whether I can use hooks in the parent functional component then pass them onto the child class component

Comment: Yes, I tried it with `useCallback` which is same hook as others. I've passed it to component and called it. You can not pass hook but it's result you can. In example you provided you pass just a result of hook. It should work. More precise example of code would be better for understanding

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code example of Functional Component as Parent and Class as Child

```
import React , {Component}from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>I Am Parent Functional Component</h1>
      <Child />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

class Child extends Component
{

  render(){
    return(
      <h2>I am Class Child Component</h2>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, however my question is am I allowed to use hooks within the parental function component, then pass on that data to a class child component. I have tried, but I received an error. (Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.). I was hoping to figure out whether the issue is due to the child component being functional.